# Chern classes of pushforwards

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, characteristic-classes, chern-classes, intersection-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper morphism of normal varieties (smooth as DM stacks, but I only care about the coarse spaces).  The map $f$ is generically finite, but not flat (so no hope of smoothness and Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch applying) and I have a fairly detailed understanding of the fiber over any point, images of $f$ restricted to divisors and so forth.

Now, take a divisor $D$, and identify it with an invertible sheaf in the standard way.  I'm looking for a way to compute the first Chern class of $f_*D$ on $Y$.

Comment: I guess you mean $D$ is a Cartier divisor, right?  (Otherwise you'll get a reflexive sheaf, but not an invertible one.)

Comment: Yes, $D$ can be taken as Cartier for this.

Comment: You can still use GRR. For example you can represent your map as a composition of a closed embedding of smooth DM stacks and a smooth map and apply GRR for each step separately.

Answer (score 7):

Do you know the (generic) degree of your map $f$?  As you probably know, standard intersection theory says $f_*[D] = n[f(D)]$ as classes in $A_{d-1}Y$, where $n$ is the degree of $f$ (restricted to $D$) and $d=\dim X = \dim Y$.  No flatness or smoothness hypotheses on $f$ are needed for this; the sticky point is in identifying these divisors with line bundles.  But since you're dealing with smooth DM stacks, that should be ok (over ${\Bbb Q}$ at least).

EDIT (incorporating the comments): For a proper map $f$, there is a map defined at the cycle level by $$f_*[D] = n\cdot [f(D)],$$ where $n$ is the degree of $D$ over $f(D)$ (i.e., degree of the induced field extension) when these have equal dimension, and $n=0$ when $\dim f(D)< \dim D$.  This passes to rational equivalence, so defines a map $A_{d-1}X \to A_{d-1}Y$.  In particular, if $f$ collapses a divisor $D$, then $f_*[D]=0$.

All this is in Fulton's *Intersection Theory*, Section 1.4.

Comment: I do, but the divisors I'm most interested in are in the non-finite locus, and so have image of smaller dimension.

Comment: Ah, that explains the question.  Well, this just means the answer is zero.  Unless I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: PS: For reference, Fulton's *Intersection Theory*, section 1.4.  (But I guess you must know this stuff.)

Comment: Is this always true, then? The homomorphism on cycles behaves nicely with respect to chern classes? My concern is that the higher codimension cycle may be the zero locus of a section of some vector bundle on $Y$, and I might have a nontrivial chern class for that.

Comment: Ah, I see now what your concern is.  You really want to do the pushforward in K-theory, and then apply the Chern character... Fortunately, GRR doesn't require anything more than *properness* of $f$ -- and, for the basic versions, smoothness of $X$ and $Y$.  I think the reduction to pushforward on Chow groups still goes through (for divisors), though, but should doublecheck this.

Comment: If you are interested in $c_1(f_*O(D))$ then the answer may be nonzero even for $D = 0$. For example, if $f:X \to Y$ is a double covering ramified in $R$ then $f_*(O) = O \oplus O(-R/2)$, so $c_1(f_*(O)) = -R/2$.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake, I'd thought GRR required smoothness of the morphism, rather than any conditions on $X$ and $Y$